# rostopic echo only a msg of topic

Tags: rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a topic containing several messages. How can I use 'rostopic echo' to echo only one message.

For example this is my topic containing the following messages:

```
Header      hdr
int32       runlevel
int32       sublevel
int32       last_seq
int32[2]    type
int32[6]    pos
float32[18]   ori
```

and I am just interested to see only message pos on my terminal.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225849/rostopic-echo-only-a-msg-of-topic/) by [Hossein](https://answers.ros.org/users/19386/hossein/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2016-02-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hossein](https://answers.ros.org/users/19386/hossein/) on 2016-02-04**:
Is there anyway to decrease the rate of publishing? It's too fast and I can't see them.

Also is there anyway to plot them?

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2016-02-04**:
please update your question, don't post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Regarding to the documentation of rostopic, this should work:

```
rostopic echo /my_topic/field_name
```

one complex example for typical tf messages:

```
rostopic echo /tf/transforms[0]/transform/translation/x
```

You can change the output rate (e.g. 1sec) with:

```
watch -n1 rostopic echo /my_topic/field_name
```

You can plot topics with [rqt_plot](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_plot)

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2016-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-02-04**:
I can confirm that the first version works. I use it frequently.

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2016-02-04**:
@ahendrix: You are right. I tried it with tf and I failed to take into account that the field "transforms" is an array.